# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, passport.js, undefined

```js
const passport = require('passport')
const User = require('../models/user')

module.exports = async (router) => {
    router
        .route('/auth/register')
        .post( async (req, res) => {
            if (req.body){
                console.log(req.body)
                //prints Object {username: "lkhjk", password: "asdas", role: 0}
                let r = await User.createUser(req.body.username, req.body.password. req.body.role) //throws error on this line
                console.log(r)
                return res.send(r)
            } else return res.status(400).send()
        })
}
```

Hello, I'm having difficulties finding why it says `req` is undefined if on the console.log it can print it without any problem.
*(bodyparser is configured and in the request it has the correct headers)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on this line:

```
let r = await User.createUser(req.body.username, req.body.password. req.body.role)
```

You have a `.` instead of a `,`. So `req.body.password.req` is undefined.

Try:

```
let r = await User.createUser(req.body.username, req.body.password, req.body.role)
```